# An Arrangement Puzzle

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

I have seven coins that are arranged below. I challenge you to take away two coins to leave 5 coins across and and three coins going down.

[image]

Comment: This is going to be some sort of [tag:wordplay] puzzle I bet....

Comment: darn, what gave it away xD @BeastlyGerbil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So..

> Trick is to take away two coins on the right - So, taking away the two coins on the right leaves only 5 coins in *a cross*...and hence we get - 
>
>  [image]
>
>  Probably, [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) tag is missing.

Comment: you might want to add the explanation for the cross in case people don't see it. but yeah, correct! :)

Comment: @thecoder16 Done! :)

Comment: Called it :P +1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could get this to work without wordplay.

> 1.) Take away the two coins on the right.
>  2.) Move the coin at the top on top of the one below it.
>  3.) Move the coin at the bottom on top of the now two above it.
>
>  Five coins across, three coins going down the center, two coins taken away.